# Azure authentication with google - how to change user?

Tags: azure, authentication, google-api

I am using Azure, and I have set up authentication with Google for my Android app and it works perfectly. However, I entered my login details the first time I authenticated, and now it re-uses those every time. They are not the same as the ones on my tablet, and I want to authenticate with those instead. How do you force the authentication process to show the login screen again? 
The authentication process is invoked with the single method call:

```
if (AzureCloudService.Instance.MobileServiceUser != null)
     {
     if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
         {
                        Android.Webkit.CookieManager.Instance.RemoveAllCookies(null);
          }else{
                        Android.Webkit.CookieManager.Instance.RemoveAllCookie();
          }
      await AzureCloudService.Instance.MobileServicesClient.LogoutAsync();

    }
```

AzureCloudService.Instance.MobileServiceUser = null;

So I can't see any options to request the login screen should be shown.
I have no idea where to look for an answer, so sorry if it is something obvious.
Thanks.